# Постоянная ошибка: ImportError: No module named 'plotly'

Tags: python

Изучаю модуль plotly. Но уже при выполнении первого примера, выдает ошибку:

> ImportError: No module named 'plotly

Установил его: sudo pip install plotly. При установке выдал:

> The directory '.........../.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.

Но установку осуществил. Затем я сделал sudo -Н pip install plotly, на что получил: Requirement already satisfied. Делал upgrade и pip, и plotly, но и дальше выдает эту ошибку. Прошу помочь! Заранее благодарю!

Использую Linux Ubuntu (64-bit).

Comment: пишет что ошибка в правах изверя, под которым вы пытаетесь установить модуль, тоесть нет разрешения на создания попки скорее всего

Comment: @Pavel Bereznichenko  
А sudo -Н pip install plotly эту проблему не решает?

Comment: -H, - установить для переменной HOME домашний каталог указанного пользователя,

Comment: pip3 install --user plotly

Comment: @andreymal Заработало! Огромная благодарность!

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, не надо мусорить в системе в обход менеджера пакетов, устанавливаем всё в домашнюю папку пользователя через `--user` и без `sudo`.

Во-вторых, мне удалось наванговать, что используется третий питон) Для Python 3 в Debian-based дистрибутивах пакеты ставятся через `pip3` (а просто `pip` это для Python 2)

Таким образом:

```
pip3 install --user plotly
```